# Wordpress: Display grandchild pages with Next and Previous link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a website where the parent page needs to display all the grandchild pages ONLY.

Apparently I have found here the solution in displaying every grandchildren pages:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-every-grandchildren?replies=18

Now my only problem is to add a previous/next link that displays n number of grandchild pages (for instance, 10)

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/D9HbHdKN

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use wp_paginate plugin of wordpress, you just have to call wp_paginate function inside your loop. All settings will e on backend!

Comment: I don't think there is a need to use for a plugin since my theme has a built-in function for the pagination (I used the default 2010 theme). I'm not much of a back end programmer, so may I ask which part of the loop should I add the navigation? Many thanks.